# I cannot use Flutter HydratedBloc on my project

Tags: flutter, bloc

I've tried many ways but I cannot find proper way to use Flutter HydratedBloc.
I cannot store bloc's state to local storage. Please help me, it took me 2 days.

Here is my main:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
  );

  HydratedBlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    },
    storage: storage,
    blocObserver: SimpleBlocObserver(),
  );
}
```

here is my task model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Task extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  bool? isDone;
  bool? isCancelled;
  bool? isCompleted;

  Task({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    this.isDone,
    this.isCancelled,
    this.isCompleted,
  }) {
    isDone = isDone ?? false;
    isCompleted = isCompleted ?? false;
    isCancelled = isCancelled ?? false;
  }

  Task copyWith({
    String? id,
    String? name,
    bool? isDone,
    bool? isCancelled,
    bool? isCompleted,
  }) {
    return Task(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      isDone: isDone ?? this.isDone,
      isCancelled: isCancelled ?? this.isCancelled,
      isCompleted: isCompleted ?? this.isCompleted,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        id,
        name,
        isCancelled,
        isCompleted,
        isDone,
      ];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'isDone': isDone,
      'isCancelled': isCancelled,
      'isCompleted': isCompleted,
    };
  }

  factory Task.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Task(
      id: map['id'] ?? '',
      name: map['name'] ?? '',
      isDone: map['isDone'],
      isCancelled: map['isCancelled'],
      isCompleted: map['isCompleted'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Task.fromJson(String source) => Task.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

I don't know if you need this in case here is my bloc_state.dart file:

```
part of my_lab;

abstract class TodosState extends Equatable {
  const TodosState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CollectingTodos extends TodosState {}

class TodosCollected extends TodosState {
  final List<Task> tasks;

  const TodosCollected({
    this.tasks = const <Task>[],
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [tasks];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'tasks': tasks.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory TodosCollected.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TodosCollected(
      tasks: List<Task>.from(map['tasks']?.map((x) => Task.fromMap(x))),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory TodosCollected.fromJson(String source) =>
      TodosCollected.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

and here is my todos_bloc.dart file:

```
library my_lab;

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:to_do_bloc/models/task.dart';

part 'todos_event.dart';
part 'todos_state.dart';

class TodosBloc extends HydratedBloc<TodosEvent, TodosState> {
  TodosBloc() : super(CollectingTodos()) {
    on<CollectTodo>(_onCollectTodo);
    on<AddTodo>(_onAddTodo);
    on<UpdateTodo>(_onUpdateTodo);
    on<DeleteTodo>(_onDeleteTodo);
  }

  void _onCollectTodo(
    CollectTodo event,
    Emitter<TodosState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(TodosCollected(tasks: event.tasks));
  }

  void _onAddTodo(AddTodo event, Emitter<TodosState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    if (state is TodosCollected) {
      emit(
        TodosCollected(
          tasks: List.from(state.tasks)..add(event.task),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void _onUpdateTodo(UpdateTodo event, Emitter<TodosState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    if (state is TodosCollected) {
      List<Task> tasks = (state.tasks.map((task) {
        return task.id == event.task.id
            ? task.isDone == false
                ? event.task.copyWith(isDone: true)
                : event.task.copyWith(isDone: false)
            : task;
      })).toList();
      emit(TodosCollected(tasks: tasks));
    }
  }

  void _onDeleteTodo(DeleteTodo event, Emitter<TodosState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    if (state is TodosCollected) {
      emit(
        TodosCollected(tasks: List.from(state.tasks)..remove(event.task)
            ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  TodosState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (state is CollectingTodos) {
      return TodosCollected.fromJson(json.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TodosState state) {
    if (state is TodosCollected) {
      return {'value': state};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more: do you get any errors, what's returned as `json` inside the `TodosState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` method, what's the expected result, what's the state you get now, etc.

Comment: hi @mkobuolys.
for example I added 3 tasks and I marked the third one as done. 
here is whole list:

TodosCollected([Task(234-234-wer, task1, false, false, false), Task(wer-234-sdvsj, task2, false, false, false), Task(08eac5c7-256c-42cb-a739-16380c940e8d, task3, false, false, true)]) // the last true means, third task is done.

Comment: then when I hot-restart it's getting this message about 200 times:
{value: {"tasks":[{"id":"234-234-wer","name":"task1","isDone":false,"isCancelled":false,"isCompleted":false},{"id":"wer-234-sdvsj","name":"task2","isDone":false,"isCancelled":false,"isCompleted":false},{"id":"08eac5c7-256c-42cb-a739-16380c940e8d","name":"task3","isDone":true,"isCancelled":false,"isCompleted":false}]}}

I/flutter (14592): TodosBloc FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
I/flutter (14592): {value: {"tasks":[{"id":"234-234-wer","name":"task1","isDone":false,"isCanc...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code and your comments, I could notice several erroneous places in this code:

```
@override
TodosState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  if (state is CollectingTodos) {
    return TodosCollected.fromJson(json.toString());
  }
}

@override
Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TodosState state) {
  if (state is TodosCollected) {
    return {'value': state};
  }
}
```

Technically, the code itself is not wrong, just there could be several problems with that:

1. HydratedBloc uses the overridden `fromJson` method during the initialisation of the bloc - are you sure you want to execute the code only when the state is `CollectingTodos`. Maybe that's ok based on your business logic needs, just double-check that.
2. The obvious thing that is wrong here is that you store your JSON object as `{'value': ...}`. I think you just copy-pasted this from the example since all you need to do inside the `toJson` is to return your state as a JSON object - the `value` property is not needed here. Currently, when you try to resolve your state from this JSON object, you do not account for this `value` part, hence your code fails.

Comment: thanks @mkobuolys.
I initialized 2 default Tasks, maybe this is the couse of going back to initial when I hot-reload.

providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => TodosBloc()
            ..add(
              CollectTodo(
                tasks: [
                  Task(
                    id: '234-234-wer',
                    name: 'task1',
                  ),
                  Task(
                    id: 'wer-234-sdvsj',
                    name: 'task2',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ),
      ],

Comment: Hmm, this `TodosBloc()..add()` is not provided in your question - I cannot confirm that. If `value` property was the problem, do not forget to mark the answer as correct 